# MySQL Single Row Multiple Columns Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables 'table A' and 'table B', I would like to select all columns from Table A (10 columns) and select 1 column from Table B so that I have 1 row with a total of 11 columns (10 from Table A and 1 from Table B).

- I would like to avoid using 'As alias_name' and use original column name
- My tables have no common ID columns
- Both my select statements returns 1 row each (1 row from Table A and 1 row from Table B)
- I just want to take my result from first select statement and join the result with second select statement to have multiple columns (1 row) and NOT a single column (so I will not be using UNION, perhaps INNER JOIN but not sure how to use it?)

The following statement is close to what I require - It returns 2 columns (alias_name, alias_imageurl) from 2 tables:

```
SELECT (SELECT name FROM `users`) AS alias_name,(SELECT imageurl FROM `pictures` WHERE profilepicture LIKE '1') AS alias_imageurl
```

The problem with the above (besides being forced to use an alias for column names) is that I can only return 1 column from Table A instead of all because the below query returns an error: Operation should contain 1 column(s)

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM `users`),(SELECT imageurl FROM `pictures` WHERE profilepicture LIKE '1') AS alias_imageurl
```

Comment: You have a very unusual set of requirements.  Can you motivate why you think these are a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT u.*, p.imageurl
FROM users u cross join
     picture p
WHERE p.profilepicture LIKE '1';
```

Comment: Unrecognized keyword. (near "cross" at position 36)

Comment: @user3560827 . . . MySQL definitely supports cross joins:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html.